# How to stretch child div vertically to fill up parent div when parent div height is dynamic

Tags: css

Mockup:

[image]

The parent div's height is dynamic; it shrinks to fit the left-hand div (the one containing the text). I'd like the right-hand div (white background, with child img) to stretch vertically to fill the parent div. Unfortunately, `height: 100%` only works when the parent div's height is statically determined.

Here's what I've got right now:

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightgray
}

.blurb {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em;
}

.decoration {
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  height: 100% // XXX does not work
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="blurb">
    Lorem ipsum...
  </div>
  <div class="decoration">
    ✓
  </div>
</div>
```

Answers to similar questions recommend using `display: table-cell;`, but then you have the issue of making the first (text) div stretch horizontally all the way, which is a different can of worms entirely.

Comment: use position:absolute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.blurb {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 2em;
}

.decoration {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="blurb">
    Lorem ipsum...
  </div>
  <div class="decoration">
    ✓
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="blurb">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis molestiae accusantium, magni commodi repellendus quidem facilis doloremque perspiciatis, ab odio omnis deleniti, obcaecati maiores dolores?
  </div>
  <div class="decoration">
    ✓
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with position property. The parent container set to `relative` and child decoration set to `absolute` with `top` and `bottom` set to 0.

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: relative;
}

.blurb {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em;
}

.decoration {
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 10px;
  /* Align the content to center */
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="blurb">
    Lorem ipsum...
  </div>
  <div class="decoration">
    ✓
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately using `position: absolute` means that the text box overlaps with the check decoration. This can be seen by adding a longer blurb.

Comment: Thanks for notifying. I thought the padding set on blurb is sufficient for the decoration.